# How to write an R if statement that selects between 2 data columns and returns one based on the value of a third column

Tags: r, if-statement

I Have a data set that looks like this:
[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kptJ.png)

I need R to take create a new column "Ref" and choose between Allele_A & Allele_B based on the value of Hom_Ref_A.

If Hom_Ref_A = 2 it should be choosing from Allele_A, and if Hom_Ref_A = 0 it should choose from Allele_B and write these to the Ref column

and the reverse for an "Alt" column (Allele_A if Hom_Ref_A = 0, and Allele_B if Hom_Ref_A = 2)

The output should look like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFQaG.png)

I would really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Please show input data using `dput` (not as images) so others can easily copy and paste it to their R session without retyping it.  See info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering how to add it because typing it made it all one line... Still learning how to ask for help I guess

Comment: Indent code lines by 4 spaces and SO will format them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `case_when`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    Ref = case_when(
      Hom_Ref_A == 2 ~ Allele_A,
      Hom_Ref_A == 0 ~ Allele_B
      ),
    Alt = case_when(
      HomRef_A == 2 ~ Allele_B,
      HomRef_A == 0 ~ Allele_A
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, except for the missing "_" between Hom and Ref in the Alt code. But still thanks